# Async methods return type

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In the code I have await in WallModel method but I can't use async. How can I use async and await in this code?

```
class WallModel
{
    public WallModel()
    {
        WallItems = new ObservableCollection<Wall>();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("XXXXX");
        string Parse_Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    }
    public ObservableCollection<Wall> WallItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `async/await` in constructor. You have to move the work to a separate method. Or use an async factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WallModel` method is actually a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) and it can't be marked `async`, so you can't use `await` within it's body either.

Comment: I have a blog post where I describe [alternatives to `async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to use await, method needs to have "async Task" in declaration
2. async constructors are not allowed.

You have few options like

1. Use asynchronous factory pattern and don't do initialization in
   constructor
2. Use asynchronous initialization pattern

If you have to go with the first option, your code may look like something like this

```
class WallModel
{
    public WallModel()
    {
        WallItems = new ObservableCollection<Wall>();            

        Initialization = InitializeAsyn();
    }

    public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

    private async Taks InitializeAsyn()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("XXXXX");
        string Parse_Text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Wall> WallItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then somewhere outside of the class

```
var instance = new WallModel();
await instance.Initialization;
```

Good article on the subject and how you can do it (as author mentioned in other answer) http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html.